# When to show a progress bar?

Tags: user-interface, usability

In an interactive application, what would you consider to be the minimal delay that a progress bar should be shown for?

The only guideline I could find is an article from 1993, which states that a progress bar should be shown for anything from 10s up [1]. Is that still the commonly accepted threshold? Or has our attention span (and expectations towards a reactive GUI) changed since then, that also smaller delays should already require some form of progress indication (beyond a wait cursor)?

[1] https://www.nngroup.com/articles/response-times-3-important-limits/

Comment: Probably better at ux.stackexchange.com

Comment: These days, users feel even a 5 seconds is a lot.
SO, I would go with every delay goes over 3 seconds !

Comment: Is there some 'official' source or guideline that would state such a short delay?